# Similar substrings in C#

Tags: c#, string, distance, levenshtein-distance

I want to provide simple feedback for typos or incomplete input.
The user is allowed to enter a couple of words, which have to be validated. The parsing has already been accomplished, so the remaining task is to suggest words from the list if one of the entered words is not already in the list.

the setup:

- I have a list of approximately 10k allowed words, each 3-30 characters long.
- The validated text consists of roughly 1 - 10 words, which have to be contained in the list.

Let me give you an example:
The list contains:

"abd", "abdcef", "axx", "def", "123abc"

The user enters:

"abc"

I'd like to show:

- "123abc" => substring
- "abd", => only 1 typo
- "abdcef", => only 1 typo/flip, otherwise substring

but not

- "axx" => 2 typos (too much for the short word length)
- "def" => 3 typos

as suggestions.

I've experimented with the Levenshtein algorithm, which works fine, if the user enters the complete word. But it fails if the user enters only a part of the word. E.g. it prefers "axx" to "abcdef", since there are only 2 changes in "axx" compared to 3 additions in "abcdef". So this doesn't work if I only enter a part of the word.

I'm thus looking for a "is similar to a substring", which prefers "add characters" in comparison to "delete/change characters".

A brute force approach with every possible substring is not an option ;-).

Comment: as far as I remember, there exists a variation of Levenshtein which allows to put a different weight on additional characters  at the begin/ned of the string

Comment: That sounds promising

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = YOUR_STRING_COLLECTION();
cbo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
cbo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
cbo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestComplete;
```

Keep coding!